# How can I get the first letter of each word in a string?

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
'Piethon is good'
```

How can I get the first letter of each word in the string? For example, the first letter of each word in the above string would be:

```
P
i
g
```

Comment: `for word in trans.split(): print(word[0])`

Comment: `[w[0] for w in trans.split()]`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get the first letter of every word in an input and put it to the end of the word

Comment: How do I get the first letter of every word from an input and put it into a variable?

Comment: `for word in trans.split(): first_char_of_word = word[0]`

Comment: @FlatBoulders I attempted to format your post into a question. If my edit was incorrect, then I'm afraid you'll have to edited the question yourself.

Comment: @ChristianDean So you got rid of the code or MCVE?  It is actually a question now though.

Comment: @Simon I removed the OP's original code, since it didn't seem to pertain to the problem he was actually describing, and then added a accurate [mcve]. So I didn't do much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[ s[0] for s in 'Piethon is good'.split() ]
```

Alternatively you could use zip on the unpacked result of split:

```
s = 'Piethon is good'

fl = next(zip(*s.split()))

print(fl) # ('P', 'i', 'g')
```

Answer (score 3):

How about you just slice the string when printing (or assign a new variable) and remove `start = word[0:][0]`:

```
trans = input("enter a sentence ")
trans = trans.lower()
t_list = trans.split()
for word in t_list:
    print(word[0])
```

This works because you get a list containing all the values of the string (by default `split()` splits white-space), next you initerate through that list (this returns a single character) and then get the value of the first character of the string.

You could also use `trans = input("enter a sentence ").lower().split()` rather than redefine `trans` into a new variable each time.